# ureadhead no such file or directory at kernel startup: how to disable not found files?

Tags: kernel, ureadahead

My kernel loading is slow so I ran a

```
journalctl -b
```

to see what was wrong and I saw that my kernel spent 4 seconds because ureadhead doesn't find some files, just as:

```
ott 25 14:01:29 andrea-Lenovo-Z50-70 ureadahead[255]: ureadahead:/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/unity-greeter.pkla: no such File o directory
```

or

`ott 25 13:33:49 andrea-Lenovo-Z50-70 ureadahead[245]: ureadahead:/usr/sbin/lightdm: no such File or directory`
(I use gdm and not lightdm)

There are 10-15 lines as that, relatives to software that I don't have on my PC. how can i tell ureadhead to don't start / don't find that because I don't have them and I don't want them? Thank you.

Comment: Delete the read ahead history file and a new up-to-date one will be built next boot.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix how can I do that?

Comment: You can google that or I'll post an answer tonight when  Ubuntu.

Comment: Find that. I deleted /var/lib/ureadahead/pack file.

Comment: I rebooted and it created the new list, but in the new log there is `ureadahead[245]: ureadahead:/var/spool/cups/tmp/cups-dbus-notifier-lockfile: no such file or directoty' that was there before and it take 2 seconds.